# jupyter notebook in binder "javascript error require is not defined"

Tags: python, jupyter

Estoy intentando ejecutar un script python que utiliza vpython y sympy como jupyter notebook en binder pero no consigo  que haga ninguna representación de vpython que sí funciona en local utilizando anaconda. Copio un ejemplo minimalista:

```
import ipympl
from vpython import *
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
scene = canvas(background=color.white, autoscale=False)
sphere()
```

No obtento ningún error pero la última celda no se ejecuta.

Comment: Copie el código y se ejecuta perfecto. Lo probé desde dentro de Pycharm, con Firefox como navegador.

Comment: El código se ejecuta bien en un jupyter notebook en local pero necesito utilizarlo online, por eso pensé en utilizar binder: https://mybinder.org/. Mi problema es utilizar el código online. Glowscript no funciona porque no permite importar librerías como sympy. Mi código real no es el que copié arriba. El código que copié es sólo una versión minimalista. Lo que necesito es ejecutar ese código en una web, sin necesidad de instalar ninguna dependencia en el ordenador desde el que lo ejecute.